# Timed out waiting for process to appear while running android instrumentation test

Tags: android, testing, fragment, androidx, android-instrumentation

I followed the example in this documentation (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/testing#create-graphical) for testing fragments. but its not working. It's giving this message - `Timed out waiting for process to appear on emulator.`
Please help me. I am stuck on this for very lo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what was the issue. I tried all the different solutions on stack overflow as well but no luck. after 3 long days of frustration, I uninstalled the android studio completely with the SDK as well and installed it fresh. And It's working now.